# click event for a div with clipPath doesn't work in angular.js

Tags: html, css, angularjs, svg, clip-path

I have some problems here. I have a div with an SVG on its border. I want to add a click event to the div, but the SVG doesn't let the click event work on div. 
Here is the template of the component:

```html
<div class="input-container dash-bordered clipped-left-borders">
    <div class="input-filed no-icon-field">
        <span class="icon-plane-left-down input-icon-font"></span>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="something" (click)="toggleDestinationDropDown(true)" />
    </div>
</div>

<svg id="clipSvg" viewBox="0 0 500 0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipLeft" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.002 0.01)">
            <path d="M-20 0 A3 2, 0, 0 0, 20 0 L20 100 A3 2, 0, 0 0, -20 100 L0 20" fill="royalblue" stroke="black" />
            <rect x="20" y="0" width="500" height="100" />
        </clipPath>

        <clipPath id="clipRight" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.002 0.01)">
            <path d="M520 0 A3 2, 0, 0 1, 480 0 L480 100 A3 2, 0, 0 1, 520 100 L500 20" fill="royalblue"
                stroke="black" />
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="480" height="100" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

This is the css:

```css
.clipped-left-borders {
  clip-path: url(#clipLeft);
}


#clipSvg {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

How can I solve this problem???

Comment: Which angular version are you using? Are you using angularjs or angular +2?

Comment: Where's the CSS because it needs to be in the same file as the clipLeft element.

Comment: The CSS is in search.component.scss file and the HTML is in search.component.html file.

Answer (score 0):

angularjs uses **ng-click** directive instead of **(click)** which is angular +2 versions syntax.

So in your HTML replace `(click)="toggleDestinationDropDown(true)"` with `ng-click="toggleDestinationDropDown(true)"`